# Update from Select error syntax on mySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute this query directly in mySql but it's not working

```
UPDATE article a
SET a.qte_art = (a.qte_art+(i.qte*1))
FROM(
        SELECT l.qte, l.article_id_article
        FROM ligne_sortie l, bon_sortie b, article a
        WHERE l.bon_sortie_id_sortie = b.id_bsr 
        AND l.article_id_article = a.id_article
        AND b.id_bsr = 1 

    ) i
WHERE a.id_article = i.article_id_article
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM(SELECT l.qte, l.article_id_article
>    FROM ligne_sortie l, bon' at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
UPDATE 
  article a, 
  (
        SELECT l.qte, l.article_id_article
        FROM ligne_sortie l, bon_sortie b, article a
        WHERE l.bon_sortie_id_sortie = b.id_bsr 
        AND l.article_id_article = a.id_article
        AND b.id_bsr = 1 

    ) i
SET a.qte_art = (a.qte_art+(i.qte*1))
WHERE a.id_article = i.article_id_article
```

The generalized query (to fill in your columns/data) would be:

```
UPDATE
  table1 AS target,
  (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2) AS source
SET
  target.column3 = source.column1
WHERE
  target.column4 = source.column2
```

This is called "multiple-table syntax", see [Update syntax manpage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code. Remove FROM after SET

```
UPDATE article a SET a.qte_art = (a.qte_art+(i.qte*1)) (
        SELECT l.qte, l.article_id_article
        FROM ligne_sortie l, bon_sortie b, article a
        WHERE l.bon_sortie_id_sortie = b.id_bsr 
        AND l.article_id_article = a.id_article
        AND b.id_bsr = 1 

    ) i WHERE a.id_article = i.article_id_article
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the update using join statement as

```
update article a
join ligne_sortie l on l.article_id_article = a.id_article
join bon_sortie b on l.bon_sortie_id_sortie = b.id_bsr 
set a.qte_art = (a.qte_art+(l.qte*1))
where b.id_bsr = 1
```